# GhostDriver with PhantomJS and Selenium (Python) - "Connection Refused"

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, ghostdriver

**The Goal:**

I am trying to perform some scraping in Python using a headless browser: Selenium with PhantomJs and GhostDriver.

I am using Python 2.7 on a Mac running Mavericks. I work within emacs (although it also didn't work from Terminal).
I have already overcome some errors such as "phantomjs - no such file or directory exists", but have got the latest Binaries from [here](https://github.com/eugene1g/phantomjs/releases), which promise to be the latest, including a pending patch from the official PhantomJS team.

**My Test Script:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

desired_cap = {
        'phantomjs.page.settings.loadImages' : True,
        'phantomjs.page.settings.resourceTimeout' : 10000,
        'phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent' : "my_user_agent"
        }

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path= "/usr/local/bin/phantomjs", desired_capabilities=desired_cap)
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
driver.get('https://google.com/')

driver.save_screenshot("testing.png")
driver.page_source("source_code.txt")

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('--*[@id=-gbqfq-]')
element.send_keys('testing')
element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Here is a link to the webdriver's simple explanation:
http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_phantomjs/selenium.webdriver.phantomjs.webdriver.html

**The Error Message:**

[image: The error message that I was getting]

**What I have tried:**

I took a simple example from a tutorial before trying to actually perform anything more complicated, but still get errors. One [tutorial](http://blog.likewise.org/2013/04/webdriver-testing-with-python-and-ghostdriver/)... a [second](http://toddhayton.com/2015/02/03/scraping-with-python-selenium-and-phantomjs/)

I made one last change to the phantomjs `service.py` file, which I found [here](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/236). Namely, I changed:

`self.process = subprocess.Popen(self.service_args,
stdout=self._log, stderr=self._log)`  to:

`self.process = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/env', 'phantomjs', '--webdriver=59202'])`

The last arguement `--webdriver` seems rather arbitrary to my inexperienced eyes. I thought it might correlate to the port that it used by ghostdriver, which is displayed after each run in the `ghostdriver.log` and is different each time. Because it changes each time, I don't think using it makes sense to have it static in the code - and after trying anyway, it didn't work.

**The Question:**

Does anybody have any ideas about why the connection is being refused??

Comment: Running this 'working' script exactly as it is from the second tutorial I mentioned produces the same 'Connection Refused' error: Here is where you can get the script from: [Github Download](https://github.com/thayton/taleo_job_scraper/blob/master/scraper.py)